# Could G-d change His mind about the future of humanity?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, messiah, messianic-redemption

Jews believe that G-d made a permanent covenant with them. We also believe He made a covenant with mankind. We believe in a Messianic redemption and ultimate restoration of the world to peace and order; we envision a just end in which those separated are reunited, the dead are raised, and humanity is united in serving G-d.

So says our theory. ([Sou](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4714-covenant#anchor3).[rces](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/108400/jewish/The-End-of-Days.htm).) But what if the covenants that were made do not technically exclude an irrevocable end (to human life, to the world) through terrific destruction? Or, far scarier: what if G-d indeed made good covenants, but in the future changes His mind (ch"v)?

Do our texts account for this possibility--do we see it as possible? Why or why not? How likely is such a thing supposed to be? And what are our souls to do then?

Comment: Please explain downvote

Comment: http://nishmablog.blogspot.com/2009/10/can-hashem-change-his-mind.html

Comment: I didn't vote at all, but the DV might be because the question body doesn't match the title -- to fix that, I'd suggest removing the first two of three questions in your second paragraph. That's really a separate idea, and more along the lines of "What if Judaism is wrong?" than "Could G-d change His mind?," which is your title. (*if you want, you could split that off into a new question; as far as I could tell, that question hasn't been asked yet here*)

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but according to my rebbetzin, the fact that we still see rainbows means that "for now" the covenant with humanity is intact. (She also says there are separate Torah grounds that it's not going to change ever and neither will Hashem's with us, but that is to be expected.)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16506/1516

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37379 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31120.

Comment: Another possibly relevant point to this question is the Jewish idea that "a bad decree can change, while a good decree will never change." Sorry, I don't have sources, except for here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66540/what-happened-with-g-ds-promise

Comment: @SAH That's absolutely relevant. The Rambam says that a negative prophecy against the Jewish people is subject to change but that a positive one is not ([*Hil. Y'sodei HaTorah* 10:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=1&perek=10&halocha=4), [English translation](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904996/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Ten.htm)). The Rambam's sources that a positive prophecy for the nation is irrevocable are [*B'rachos* 7a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=7&format=text) and [*Yirm'yahu* 28:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1128.htm#9).

Comment: @Fred I'd love it if either you or I could add that as an answer, so it doesn't disappear. Would you rather have the time or the reputation points? :)

Comment: @SAH Be my guest. :) But know that my comment doesn't fully cover that aspect of the topic; for some more, see [this article](http://www.aishdas.org/student/navi.htm), as well as *Lechem Mishneh* (ad loc.) who defends the Rambam by limiting the case of an irrevocable positive decree to wherever at least one of the following conditions were met: 1. The prophet stated it explicitly and in God's name. 2. The people did not relinquish their merit through sin. Even the single exception mentioned in *Shabbos* 55a may not be an exception, as the overt meaning of the prophecy was not cancelled.

Comment: @Fred Thank you so much for this great information! You are probably the biggest offender of this site's policy that comments must be expendable. One thing, though--I didn't find the Lechem Mishneh ad. loc. (or anywhere at all) so cannot see the "exception mentioned in Shabbos 55a" nor understand what your comment about that is saying; please explain...

Comment: @SAH There's a (sort of) English summary of *Shabbos* 55 [here](http://dafyomi.co.il/shabbos/points/sh-ps-055.htm) (see the section 1:c:2, starting "Rav Acha b'Rebbi Chanina"). Or see the English translation [here](http://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_55.html) (beginning "For R. Aha b. R. Hanina said"). The Talmud interprets *Y'chezkeil* 9:6 as implying that the protection mentioned in [*Y'chezkeil* 9:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1209.htm#4) was revoked.

Comment: @Fred I'm struggling to understand this. When you say the protection was "revoked," does this mean that the tzadikim in this case were also slaughtered? ..If so, what do you mean by "[it] may not be an exception, as the overt meaning of the prophecy was not cancelled?"

Comment: @Fred Also--What about the loss of z'chus avos; wouldn't that be another example where G-d terminated a contract?

Comment: @SAH By "revoked," I do mean that many of the tzadikim were also slaughtered. The Talmud reads the intention behind the verses to be that, in verse 4 and the start of verse 6, the righteous elders were to be given protection, but they were excluded from the protected category at the end of verse 6. However, this meaning is not explicit; the verses are more simply read to mean that the righteous elders that were killed were never included in the protected category. So the deeper, hidden meaning is that the decree was changed, but the simple meaning of the original prophecy was not falsified.

Comment: @SAH Regarding *z'chus avos*, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22552. It's not clear practically what that statement means (and Tosafos also point to a contrary source in *Vayikra Rabba*). The Ri and the Zohar say it was only lost for the wicked. Rabbeinu Tam says the "*z'chus*" ended but the covenant of the forefathers still endures (and we still invoke it when asking for divine mercy, e.g. in the Rosh HaShana Mussaf); he appears to have an alternative version of Shmuel's prooftext. Anyway, I don't think those who say "*z'chus avos*" ended view it as a contract in the first place.

Comment: @Fred Thanks so much. I edited the answer; not sure how close it is to correct, though. Please let me know what could be improved.

Comment: @Fred The "exception" in Y'chezkel that you point out--and your reasoning for why it was not necessarily an exception--call to mind the part of my question that said "But what if the covenants that were made do not technically exclude an irrevocable end (to human life, to the world) through terrific destruction?" Somehow, I don't find "G-d kept His promise; we just didn't understand it properly" to be a very reassuring explanation for any of these

Comment: @SAH The Rambam himself takes the gemara at face value that it was a real exception. I was just speculating that the wording of the gemara ("No good expression left the mouth of the Holy One Blessed be He that he then cancelled for evil, except for this thing") could be interpreted as meaning that while God told Gavriel to protect certain people but He then changed the decree, the words of the prophecy to Ezekiel were ambiguous enough that the simple meaning of the prophecy remained in force even though God revised His heavenly command re. the scope of who would be in the protected category.

Comment: @SAH ... You are right that this approach could have opened the door to saying any good public prophecy could simply be reinterpreted to any meaning that seems to easily fit the words (which could be a slippery slope, as you note, because that might be subjective), except for the fact that the gemara says this example from Ezekiel is the solitary exception. Everywhere else, the precise original intent behind any good public decree must be upheld. But anyway, the Rambam (and seemingly Rashi, too) maintains that this was an actual exception where a good prophecy was rescinded.

Comment: @SAH I think the answer is fine (+1). However, there are a couple more potential ideas that may also bear looking into in relation to this question. 1.) The gemara where R' Akiva confirms that prophecy of the future redemption will certainly come to fruition (*Makos* 24a-b, [English](http://dafyomi.co.il/makos/points/ma-ps-024.htm)). (2.) The idea that prophecy accompanied with an oath is immutable, even regardless of whether it is good. (3.) The nature of our eternal and immutable covenant is beyond that of an ordinary prophecy that promises some good event.

Comment: @SAH By the way, regarding (2.) in my preceding comment, the Talmud states ([*Rosh HaShana* 18a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=18&format=text), [translated summary](http://dafyomi.co.il/rhashanah/points/rh-ps-018.htm)) that a divine decree accompanied with an oath is immutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

God knows the future and therefore He cannot regret and "change His mind". He is not bound to time, all of the past and the future are before Him simultaneously as something in the present (as the Rambam wrote on the mishna in Rosh Hashana "all are examined in one sweeping look").

He also told us the covenant with the Jewish people is permanent through His prophets as for example:

> "So says the Lord who gives the sun to illuminate by day, the laws of
>   the moon and the stars to illuminate at night, who stirs up the sea
>   and its waves roar, the Lord of Hosts is His Name. If these laws
>   depart from before Me, says the Lord, so will the seed of Israel cease
>   being a nation before Me for all time" ([Jeremiah 31:34](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1131.htm#34)).

Comment: I think your quote illustrates exactly the opposite of what you're saying; namely, that the covenant with Israel is *not* permanent, but conditional

Comment: @sah conditional on what? the laws of physics?

Comment: @ray Sure. Why not? God could change those. IAE you should change "cannot" to "will not" in your answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA He cannot change His mind. because change does not apply to Him

Comment: @ray And because He doesn't have a mind...

Comment: @DoubleAA then how did He make yours?

Comment: @ray yep. Those, too, are within G-d's purview.

Comment: @ray Although I can't get over that part, I think your first paragraph is a great answer to my question

Comment: @SAH took out just for u

Comment: @ray Put it back and I'll accept your answer! :)

Comment: @SAH The quote does not suggest the covenant is conditional. The nevi'im use these sort of rhetorical devices frequently (cf. [*Y'sha'yahu* 54:10](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1054.htm#10), as well as the verses leading up to it, which essentially answers your question, too). Yirm'yahu is essentially saying that, just as those things won't happen, so too God's special relationship with the Jewish people will never end.

Answer (score 2):

Another point possibly relevant to this question is the Jewish idea that a bad decree can change, but a good decree cannot. @Fred provides the source:

"The Rambam says that a negative prophecy against the Jewish people is subject to change but that a positive one is not ([Hil. Y'sodei HaTorah 10:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=1&perek=10&halocha=4), [English translation](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904996/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Ten.htm)). The Rambam's sources that a positive prophecy for the nation is irrevocable are [B'rachos 7a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=7&format=text) and [Yirm'yahu 28:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1128.htm#9)."

The nature of prophecy, how we test it, and how we know whether to believe it are discussed productively [here](http://www.aishdas.org/student/navi.htm). Fred adds to these remarks that the [Lechem Mishneh](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=90480&rid=87) "defends the Rambam by limiting the case of an irrevocable positive public decree to wherever at least one of the following conditions were met:

1. The prophet stated it explicitly and in God's name.
2. The people did not relinquish their merit through sin."

A possible exception to these laws of irrevocability is an incident in Chapter 9 of Ezekiel, about which Rav Acha b'Rebbi Chanina says in Shabbos 55a, "Only once, Hash-m said to do something good and retracted." In this incident, Hashem seems to promise to protect certain group of righteous men from slaughter (Y'chezkeil 9:4), but then they are slaughtered anyway (Y'chezkeil 9:6). The Talmud [interprets this incident](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/shabbos/points/sh-ps-055.htm) as G-d's revoking His promise. But Fred points out that depending on how one reads the verses, it may be understood that those who were slaughtered were not essentially included in G-d's original protection, suggesting that this need not have been an outright revocation of the decree.

Presumably, the covenants mentioned in this question fall under the above conditions as "irrevocable positive decrees"--although the question of whether we have, or could still, relinquish our merit through sin (ch"v) is a good one.

Comment: It is also probable that, even according to the Abarbanel's dissenting view (described in the linked article) that a positive prophecy can be nullified through sin, a good prophecy that implicitly does not depend on merit (or is made in spite of sinfulness, such as the passage from Isaiah mentioned in [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64025/could-g-d-change-his-mind-about-the-future-of-humanity?noredirect=1#comment184603_64030)) could not be nullified by sin.

Comment: Just to clarify, in case my wording was unclear: In the Rambam's opinion (even according to the Lechem Mishne's understanding of the Rambam), a positive national prophecy for the Jewish people cannot be nullified through sin so long as the prophecy was stated explicitly and in God's name. There may be other opinions that disagree with the Rambam about this (see linked article), but even they don't necessarily maintain that *all* good prophecies can be nullified through sin. For one possible category of good prophecies that might be immutable, see the comment immediately above this.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49008 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1540.

Answer (score 1):

**Malachi 3:6**

> כִּי אֲנִי יְהֹוָה לֹא שָׁנִיתִי וְאַתֶּם בְּנֵי־יַעֲקֹב לֹא כְלִיתֶם
>
> For I am the Lord, I do not change; therefore you sons of Jacob are not consumed.
>
> (Soncino translation)

In particular see Malbim’s commentary there, where this verse is specifically a reference to not reneging on the covenant and therefore not destroying Israel:

> כי אני ה׳ לא שניתי מעולם את דברי והבטחתי ואני הבטחתי להאבות בל אכלה אתכם ובאשר לא שניתי את הבטחתי לכן אתם בני יעקב לא כליתי

Answer (score 0):

I completely forgot that our tradition actually has an answer for this: It seems G-d does not destroy the world because of the merit of the lamed-vovniks.

Comment: Can you source this tradition?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not qualified to consult the original source, but the claim has been sourced here: http://neveshalom.org/html/arts/art_gallery_legend36.htm

Comment: See [*Chullin* 92a](http://dafyomi.co.il/chulin/points/ch-ps-092.htm) that the world exists in the merit of 45 tzadikim and/or that the nations of the world exist in the merit of 30 righteous non-Jews. Though the Talmud does refer to 36 lofty tzadikim who potentially merit clear encounters with the divine presence daily ([Sanhedrin 97b](http://dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/points/sn-ps-097.htm), [Sukka 45b](http://dafyomi.co.il/sukah/points/su-ps-045.htm)). (Incidentally, see Sanhedrin 97 about the effect of sin or lack of repentance on the eventual arrival of the redemption).

Comment: There are also other statements of Chazal about things whose merit sustains the world, e.g. Torah study ([*Sanhedrin* 99b](http://dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/points/sn-ps-099.htm), see Abaye's statement in section 5-J of the translation).

Comment: "Other statements": For example, according to R'Shimon ben Gamliel, "the world endures by virtue of three things: justice, truth, and peace" (Pirkei Avos 1:18).